# Simple Stored Procedure for learning

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

My journey is progressing and I'm learning rapidly. I can't get enough of this stuff... alas I am at a dead end here and need some help.

I am running Visual Studio, am connected to a database (that's filled with dummy data). I am able to run queries on it as expected. However, I'm learning about Procedures right now and I'm coming up with a problem.

I am trying to simply run a query that will select all from table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE nearthetop()
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE VOLUME = (SELECT MAX(VOLUME) FROM RESULTS WHERE VOLUME NOT In (SELECT Max(VOLUME) from RESULTS))
END;
```

When I run this inside Visual Studio I get an error:

```
EXECUTE FAIL:

  CREATE PROCEDURE twofromtop() BEGIN SELECT * FROM RESULTS WHERE VOLUME = (SELECT MAX(VOLUME) FROM RESULTS WHERE VOLUME NOT In (SELECT Max(VOLUME) from RESULTS)) END

Message :

  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END' at line 3
```

When I remove BEGIN and END; from the procedure it creates it fine.
Why is that?

And then, once created, how do I "call" that procedure so as I can see the returned results?

Comment: @Littlefoot provides a spot-on answer, but misses one big item. For you it falls into the category of *check your basic assumptions*. PL/SQL is primarily an Oracle RDBMS language, but your error message indicates something else entirely: *check the manual that corresponds to your **MySQL server version*** Even though Oracle Corporation owns MySQL does not mean the databases are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, when PL/SQL code uses a `SELECT` statement, you have to select **into** something - a local variable, a collection, whatever - or use a cursor loop and deal with cursor variable.

You're selecting row(s) whose `volume` value is the 2nd largest. Code you wrote *works*, but it fetches from the same table 3 times which isn't optimal. For example (based on Scott's sample schema), fetching the 2nd largest salary:

```
SQL> select ename, sal from emp order by sal desc;

ENAME             SAL
---------- ----------
KING             5000   --> largest
FORD             3000   --> Ford and Scott both share
SCOTT            3000   --> the 2nd largest salary
JONES            2975
BLAKE            2850
CLARK            2450
<snip>
```

Your query returns correct result:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from emp
  3  where sal = (select max(sal) from emp
  4               where sal not in (select max(sal) from emp)
  5              );

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20
```

Consider doing it differently:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select e.*,
  3               rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk
  4        from emp e
  5       )
  6  where rnk = 2;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO        RNK
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20          2
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20          2

SQL>
```

---

Now, back to your procedure. A simple option which doesn't require much effort is to use a cursor `FOR` loop. Procedure's `IN` parameter says *which* largest salary you want:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure nearthetop (par_n in number) as
  2  begin
  3    for cur_r in (select *
  4                  from (select e.*,
  5                          rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk
  6                        from emp e
  7                       )
  8                  where rnk = par_n
  9                 )
 10    loop
 11      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.ename ||': '|| cur_r.sal);
 12    end loop;
 13  end;
 14  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin
  2    nearthetop(2);        --> give me the 2nd largest salary
  3  end;
  4  /
SCOTT: 3000
FORD: 3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2    nearthetop(5);        --> give me the 5th largest salary
  3  end;
  4  /
BLAKE: 2850

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

I'm just displaying those values on the screen; you never said what you'd want to do with them.

---

If you'd like to **return** the result to the caller, a better option is to use a function instead of a procedure. In this case, it would be a ref cursor it returns.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_nearthetop (par_n in number)
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  as
  4    rc sys_refcursor;
  5  begin
  6    open rc for select *
  7                  from (select e.*,
  8                          rank() over (order by sal desc) rnk
  9                        from emp e
 10                       )
 11                  where rnk = par_n;
 12    return rc;
 13  end;
 14  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> var l_rc refcursor
SQL>
SQL> exec :l_rc := f_nearthetop(2);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :l_rc

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE        SAL       COMM     DEPTNO        RNK
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 09.12.82       3000                    20          2
      7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03.12.81       3000                    20          2

SQL>
```

---

So, yes - there are various options. Which one you'll actually use depends on what you want to do.

(As of Visual Studio: I can't help about it, I don't use it.)